asp classic - asp.net - Need a Large File Download Script that downloads in chunks that does not load the entire file into memory
I have run into an issue that I cannot find a solution for.
Specs:
ESXi 6.5
Windows 2016 Datacenter
ARR Web Farm
--Current Temp Setup  (Both systems have almost identical settings.)
1 ARR Server  (8GB RAM)
1 Web Server  (8GB RAM)
(Tested, going through the ARR server.
Then tested going straight to the Web Server.
Both give the exact same results.)
The problem is allowing files over 2 GB to be downloaded from our IIS 10 Server.
At the moment, I've had to split the files into smaller 1GB chunks to allow people to download them. Though this does work, I would prefer the original-sized file be downloaded in one hit.
I have this code for Classic ASP.
I've updated the code as suggested by Iłya Bursov
<%
csfiles = "R710_firmware.zip" '2.14GB file

strfileName = csfiles

Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","filename=" & strfileName
Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed" 'Here your content -type

Dim strFilePath, lSize, lBlocks
'Const CHUNK = 20480
'Const CHUNK = 20480000
Const CHUNK = 8192 ' Updated
Server.ScriptTimeout = 600 '10 minutes
set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Open
objStream.Type = 1
objStream.LoadFromfile Server.MapPath("up/files/"&strfileName) 
lSize = objStream.Size
Response.AddHeader "Content-Size", lSize
lBlocks = 1
Response.Buffer = False
Do Until objStream.EOS Or Not Response.IsClientConnected
Response.BinaryWrite(objStream.Read(CHUNK))
Response.Flush() ' Updated
Loop

objStream.Close
%>

Web.config
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>

IIS Settings

Set MIME Types
.iso application/octet-stream
IIS/ASP
Response Buffering Limit: 200000000
IIS/Request Filtering
Maximum allowed content length (Bytes)
4294967295 (4gb)

In the ApplicationHost.config
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength ="4294967295" />

In the logs, I see this when I try to download a larger file, 2 GB or higher.

/TimerDownload1.asp Entry=3085|18|800a0e89| Data_value_is_too_large_to_be_represented_by_the_field_data_type.

UPDATED ERROR LOG INFORMATION

Error:  -ASP_LOG_ERROR
LineNumber:  19
ErrorCode:  800a0e89
Description:  Data value is too large to be represented by the field
data type.

This will be line 19
lSize = objStream.Size

While reading other forum threads from 10+ years ago, it seems that the reason this might be happening is that the system is trying to load the file into the server memory before downloading it, and this may be the cause of the page erroring out or giving a 0 kb file download size.
I have available RAM that I can throw to the VMs, which is an option if I have to do that.
However, I would really like to send only a chunk at a time to memory, have that downloaded, then send another chunk, and so forth—without sending everything at once.
If anyone may know of a way to either:

Make the existing script work by downloading smaller Memory chunks.
An ASP.NET script that will download smaller memory chunks for large 2GB^ files.

Yes, I am willing to use an ASP.NET solution.
And yes, I have looked for some, but they all seem to be for Razor or ASP.NET Core.
Thank you.

after Response.BinaryWrite(objStream.Read(CHUNK)) try to add Response.Flush()

probably error comes form read, try to reduce chunk size, start with something like 8kb - 8192 bytes

Updated code on my side as well as the post itself. The issues still exist, unfortunately.  Looking over the FailedReqLogFiles files right now.

Please have a look at the section -- UPDATED ERROR LOG INFORMATION

Classic ASP is not ASP.Net they are two different things.

What? I did not say they were the same; You need to re-read what I wrote. Here, I will provide it for you...... Yes, I am willing to use an ASP.NET solution.

@CodingEE Then don't bring it up, that's not how asking questions works here. You don't just give a shopping list of what solutions you'd prefer, if you want an ASP.Net solution ask an ASP.Net question.

OK, finally figured it out.
I took a look at this script from here asp-classic-download-file-script and changed it to work with how I am getting my file data. I was able to make it work by downloading the entire 2.14GB file, so I looked at my code.
I did not want to use someone else's code, but I wanted to figure out why the code I have used for years on our site would not download the larger, over 2GB files.
I started dissecting my own code, trying to see what was unnecessary and remove it. Bit by bit, and wa-la, it downloaded the 2.14GB file. With a huge smile across my face, I started writing this up.
So, taking from what I have above, to a fully working large file download.
The following was removed in order to make it work.
lSize = objStream.Size
Response.AddHeader "Content-Size", lSize
lBlocks = 1
Response.Buffer = False

Full code
<%
csfiles = "R710_bootable.iso"

strfileName = csfiles

Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment; filename=" & strfileName

Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Dim strFilePath, lSize, lBlocks

Const CHUNK = 8192
Server.ScriptTimeout = 600 '10 minutes
set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Open
objStream.Type = 1
objStream.LoadFromfile Server.MapPath("up/files/"&strfileName) 

Do Until objStream.EOS Or Not Response.IsClientConnected
Response.BinaryWrite(objStream.Read(CHUNK))
Response.Flush()
Loop

objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing

%>

Hope this will help out others.
Thank you to Iłya Bursov for trying to help. It is much appreciated.
